# Is there a collective term to describe "coffee" and "tea"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, hypernyms

Any term to describe both of them — coffee and tea collectively?

I wanted to call it *beverages* but that also includes drinks outside coffee and tea. Also, I could call it *hot drinks* but that would also include any hot beverages.

Any ideas to call both of them collectively?

Comment: as far as brewed beverages go, do you want to exclude herbal (chai) teas and hot chocolates?

Comment: @Moak, just coffee and tea will do. From my understanding, brewed beverages also include herbal tea right?

Comment: Tea leaves are from the camellia sinensis plant so drinks brewed with herbal stuff aren't tea, they should properly be called *tisanes*.

Comment: In the UK, we would refer to a having a kettle in a hotel room as "tea and coffee making facilities". It's the generally accepted term.

Comment: I'm not sure what good this question does. It's quite uninteresting to me and I can't think of a reason why anyone would need the term. -1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really, there isn't.

**Caffeinated drinks or beverages** might be more accurate, but that could include energy drinks, pre-workout supplements, a lot of other hot drinks that might contain coffee such as Mochas, etc It also becomes a problem when you introduce decaf cofffee or decaf tea. Redbush tea has little to no caffeine, so this won't work.

While it would be technically correct and understood by most, you might come off as a little awkward or pedantic asking someone if they want a caffeinated beverage in day to day use. I would expect to see the term in more scientific/academic/informative contexts, e.g. "the average temperature of a caffeinated beverage"

If you really need a word or phrase for day to day use, here's a few more colloquial alternatives that would work in the UK:

- "a cuppa?"
- "a brew?"
- "Tea & Coffee?"

Though none are standard aside from the last. They're mostly subjective, and vary from region to region.

**Or more simply, just ask if they'd like a drink**

But there is a specific whimsical beverage if you're looking for a joke:

**"Teaffee"**

- 2 tablespoons coffee
- 6 tea bags
- 64 ounces water

Read more: http://www.food.com/recipe/teaffee-247421#ixzz1eiMHGECp

However, this is a strange term that most english speakers will have never heard of, and you won't find it in any dictionary.

Comment: Nice one - I think I can still use this `Teafee` in my context.

Comment: I live in Italy, and the site tells me it is not available in my country. I only see a blank page.  Could you report the relevant lines, please? I can also assure you that in my 52 years I have never come across the blend word "teaffee" my first instinct would be to say it's a typo for *toffee* (a sticky chewy sweet).

Comment: @Mari-LouA neither can I, my guess is their GDPR implementation involves blocking all EU visitors. Suffice to say everything worth reading is already in the answer

Answer (score 3):

*Caffeinated hot beverages* would narrow it down a bit, but this would also include [mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mate_%28beverage%29), which isn't tea.

If such a word exists I'd like to have it on a t-shirt, with a big love heart.

Answer (score 0):

Here in Britain they're collectively known as *beverages* or, more prosaically, as *hot drinks*. In more refined circles this implicitly includes such high-faluting things as green tea, mate, bush *tea* and hot cordials like Ribena.

Comment: "Beverage" alone does not imply the drink is hot.

Comment: Strictly speaking it doesn't, a pedant would probably say 'would you like a hot beverage' and this is what Wikipedia goes with (http://bit.ly/vmqypM), and in  popular usage it tends to fall back to that default meaning. People tend to say 'cold drinks' to cover fizzy drinks, juice, water and so on.